# GIMP: Paint a selection and maintain various levels of opacity

Tags: gimp, transparency

I'm trying to recolor a png file using GIMP.

The image I want to recolor is a solid color, but the edges are feathered with varying degrees of opacity to make the final image look smoother.

is there a way to recolor the object and maintain the varying levels of opacity without going through recoloring pixel by pixel?

(I also have the file in .psd format as well)

[image: File I want to recolor]

Comment: Hi Bradley, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the color of this object properly?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GIMP 2.8 you can simply lock the transparency of a layer while editing. Then, no operations will affect the existing transparency levels of a layer while you edit with any tools or filters.

Just click on the checkbox for that on the Layers Dialog (`ctrl + L`)

[image: Layers Dialog]

Answer (score 2):

A rather quick way to colorize a monochrome object with variable transparency on a transparent background is using the bucket fill tool with fill *FG color fill* and fill mode *Color*. This will replace the object's color by the chosen foreground color leaving transparency levels untouched:

Source:

[image]

"Color" bucket fill green:

[image]