# How can I change the blue in this icon to an exact Hex color value?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Please I need help I have an Icon image with a blue background and I need to change that blue color into a #6fdc29.

I have tried to change it in Photoshop but I don't know how + The color cover all the image, not the blue part.

It's all one layer:

[image]

Comment: related and possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly/26574#26574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the color of this object properly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly)

Comment: There are so many possible ways of doing this... using the search tool on our website or google would bring you lots of answers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [colouring an icon accurately](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111638/colouring-an-icon-accurately)

Answer (score -3):

Based on your text it shows like you are using Magic wind tool or some auto color selection tool to slect the Blue area. Due to similar contrast other parts of icon also inherting same.

Try with some Lasoo tool or Pen tool to select the background....may it will help you.

i just selected your green colour, and adjusted with hue/saturation. The below colour is very closed one.

[image]
[image]

i prefer you use lasoo tool for exact colour change,

Comment: Hi Anil, please specify what you do with the selection after making it. You show an image of a Hue/Saturation adjustment, but don't explain it in your answer.

Comment: How can I enter heo/saturation in the Photoshop?

Comment: from top menu bar Image > adjustments > Hue/saturation

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: You are welcome upvote dear :)

Comment: Just a question how to get #6fdc29 exactly , can you help me in this.

Comment: ya for this ..need to go with using Lasoo or Pen tool, then change the background.

Comment: Also, do you are a great teacher!

Comment: Any help in web coding I can help you since you helped me, my friend.

Comment: It seems like you didn't explain how you changed the shadow color as well. Did you do a color overlay for that section? It should be included in your answer.

Comment: As and when you use Hue/Satuaration, default the whole image colour will change not required to selct seperately the shadow. In the above case it's not a drop shadow so hue/saturation color change is fine.