# colouring an icon accurately

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, icon

I am a coder really, and I have to recolour an icon - and I can't get it work.
Here is the icon [image: phone icon]

I need it to be #df2526

I created a new adjustment layer that is hue saturation and click colorize (as per another post here)

But I can't see a way to accurately set the colour - i can drag the 'hue' slider along where I like so its any colour.

i tried using the color picker to get the HSL numbers, but if I transfer the numbers over the don't give the right color.
[image: color picker]

how do I get the icon colour more accurate please?

Comment: If the icon is in a svg format, you could open it in a text editor and paste the hex code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Menu Image** > **Mode** > **Grayscale**
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustments** > **Levels** > **Auto**
- **Menu Image** > **Mode** > **Duotone**
- From the **Duotone Window** choose **Monotone** and click the color
- From the **Color Picker** type the Hex Number
- **Menu Image** > **Mode** > **RGB**

[image: recolor]

**Added**

A grayscale image is an 8-bit image, it has 256 levels of gray. Transforming this image into a monotone-duotone, we get an 8-bit image, but 256 levels of the chosen color.

Comment: Why use Duotone for this?

Comment: Duotone it's not just for getting image printing, you can use it for several effects like in this case, to change a b&w image into one hexadecimal color RGB image. There are many ways, but with this you are 100% sure your black will be the Hex you want.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I found this one worked best for me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a Hue Adjustment layer. Use a Color Fill Layer

[image]

Then just set it to be a clipping mask if your icon is on a transparent background:

[image]

If it's not on a transparent background then you can either use Blend-If or Channels to achieve the same results.

[image]

In this particular case I'd just use the Red channel to make a layer mask which is how I got it on a transparent background for the first example.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I found that this didn't work for me. When I then tried with a jpg rather than a png it did work - however, it looked quite pixelated.