# How do I change my logo in png to white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, logo, png

I am trying to give a logo a white variant so it is easier to use when i design flyers or for marketing videos. I tried using the paint bucket tool but it did not work. Any help will be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Why are you doing this in photoshop? Why not in the same (vector) app as it was generated?

Comment: Layer style: [Color overlay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwRTn7uDhfk). White color, no blend mode, 100% opacity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of this object properly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly)

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the layer in the layers panel
2. Engage the *Lock Transparent Pixels* button in the layers panel
3. Do *Edit > Fill*, choose white as the fill colour

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the answer I gave a few years ago [to this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly) :)

Comment: ok then i took the answer too literally i suppose

Answer (score -1):

add a background layer and make it white make sure the layer is behind your logo

Comment: I do not think the user is asking how to add a white background, they want to turn their logo to white with a transparent background.